# Match function parameters with Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I created a Regex which allows to capture the parameters of a function.

The parameters are separated by the character **,**

You can have the character **,** inside a parameter like 'lorem, impum'

The regex returns only the last match.

My Regex :

```
\s*(\'.+\'|\".+\"|[^,]+)?(?:\s*,?\s*(\'.+\'|\".+\"|[^,]+))*
```

function parametes

```
111111111111,'222222222',"33333333333333"
```

LInk to regex exemple : https://regex101.com/r/fdRJ92/2

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: i need to catch only simple parameters stirng or number

Comment: the desired output is a list of all parameters, in this case 11,'test',"this is, a test"  => [11, "test", "this is, a test"]

Comment: Good luck with `'I, don\'t like to be simple, you understand?'`

Comment: "parameters" needs more definition. What do you accept as a parameter? You give as examples numbers and strings with either single or double quotes. What about escapes characters (`"\"\\"`)? What about numbers with decimals (`11.11`)? What about variables (`foo`)? Variables with property accessors (`foo.bar, baz["bat"]`)? Functions `11, foo("22"), 33`? With enough complexity, you simply won't be able to achieve the desired result with regexes alone. You'll need a proper parser (like PegJS). You also haven't mentioned which language/API you are using (though I assume JS from the `'/"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var rx = /(?:^|,)\s*((('|").*?(?<!\\)(\3))|(\d?\.?\d+))/g;
var str = `"21312\\'\\"3123\\"", 111111111111,'222222\\'222',"333333333,33333", 1234, .123, 0.3, '454'`;
var match;
while (match = rx.exec(str)) console.log(match[1]);
```

Output

```
"21312\'\"3123\""
111111111111
'222222\'222'
"333333333,33333"
1234
.123
0.3
'454'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `/\(?([^,\)]+)[\),]?/` :

- matching an optional opening '(' (required to catch 1st parameter)
- catch multiple characters that are NOT a (',' or ')' )
- ending in either a ',' or a ')' (required for the last parameter)

Caution as this regex indeed assumes only simple strings or numbers. It will fail on the string as mentioned by @MonkeyZeus.

If commas are used IN an argument sentence, you're in trouble as a regex looks for tokens, not token context (separator or interpunction ?).
You could try to exchange interpunction commas with a recognisable sequence, then split the arg list, then change the sequence back to a comma.

Example at https://regex101.com/r/xTkocI/1

Comment: Fails for `foo, "bar, baz", bat` and `11, bar(22, 33), 44`

Comment: Yes - that's why I wrote the last paragraph ... . And 11, bar(22, 33), 44 does not correspond to the request of simple strings and numbers.